# set git safe.directory globally on jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Team, I have like 100 bash scripts to run and my first script is erroring out stating dubious ownership. is there a way I can set this globally on jenkins instead of adding the line in every bash script?

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/verify'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/verify
```

Comment: Why is the user that runs the job not in the group of the directory like `/home/jenkins/agent/workspace`?

Comment: am not sure how to do that